# ActiveRecord validators chaining

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true,
  validates :name, length: { minimum: 4, maximum: 255 }
end
```

If "name" value is missing all the validators will run and I will get 2 errors: one from presence validator and one from length validator, "name" being too short. How can I chain these two so first failure stops the validation queue.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that should do the trick but I thought are other "proper" ways to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't want to do that,

what you probably want to do is edit the view helper that's rendering the errors to only show you the first error in a chain of every attribute, and then you'll probably want to switch places of the length and presence validators :)

I get what you mean when you say "what if we have some validators down the road which do some extensive work", and afaik there's no elegant in-built way to do this.

There's the workarounds in forms of custom validators that return false thus halting the callback chain and using `:if` and `:unless` gymnastics as explained in the other question.

Check out how [ActiveModel::Validations#run_validations!](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveModel/Validations/run_validations!) works (poke the objects with pry), you might get some insights there that will enable you to hack together a more elegant solution to your question - not very elegant mind you, the use of the hacked method could be elegant but the implementation itself will probably be pretty hackish.

---

Having said all that, the thing to keep from this post is:

you're probably optimizing prematurely at this point and the heavy validations that you *might* do at some point will probably be made using a different, more layered, architecture (with form class with its custom set of validators for example, see Form class in [7 Patterns to Refactor Fat ActiveRecord Models](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/))

Comment: The example from above is quite simple but that's not always the case. What if we have some validators down the road which do some extensive work (like db query, api query etc.). Doesn't make sense to go through the entire chain since we already have a failure.

Comment: I'm not prematurely optimizing, I'm just learning active record :). Just wondered if i can do that. Thank you for your answer!